# JavaScript anidados, Ajax

Tags: javascript, javamail

Tengo el siguiente script:

El primer Ajax se dedica en registrar, posteriormente si todo salió bien revisa si el campo "mail" es A en el caso que lo sea ejecuta una función que crea un jasper y lo guarda en mi pc, una vez que haya finalizado la función del jasper ejecuta la función del correo que adjunta el pdf del jasper ya anteriormente ejecutado, quiero mejorar en *JavaScript* y quiero saber sus opiniones de como podría mejorar este script (Funciona pero es muy sucio), de ante mano les agradezco cualquier comentario.

```
function crearBalance() {
    var mail = document.getElementById("correo").value;
    var datings = document.getElementById("fecha").value;
    var idturn = document.getElementById("idTurnobal").value;
    var usexr=document.getElementById("usernamex").value;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"CrearBalance.action", data:"tms="+$("#tms").val()+"&ContenidoMetalicoCabeza="+$("#contenidoMetalicoCabeza").val()+"&ContenidoMetalicoSR="+$("#contenidoMetalicoSR"),
            success:function(result){
            swal({title: "Buen trabajo", text: "Se ingresaron los datos del balance para su revision!", type: "success"}).then(function() {
                location.reload();     //location.href = 'perfil.php';
            });
      
            if(mail ==  'A'){
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "reportpdf.action",  
                    //  data:"asunto="+datings+"&msg="+idturn+"&usuarios="+usexr,
                    async: false,
                    success: ()=>{
                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url:"Correos.action",
                            data:"asunto="+datings+"&msg="+idturn+"&usuarios="+usexr,
                            success:function(result) { }, 
                            error: function(result){
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        });
                    }, 
                    error: function(result){
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            } else {

            }

        },
        error: function(result){
            demo.showSwal('error');
        }
    }); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mejorar tu código hay varios aspectos que puedes mejorar

1- Según la lógica de tu código, no hay necesidad de que estén anidados, a menos que por backend si sea necesario que se haga 1 detrás de otras, en ese caso no deberías hacer una solicitud por cada acción si no que lo haces todo desde backend. (Dependiendo de donde montes tu pagina, siempre es recomendable hacer la menor cantidad de peticiones al servidor)

2- Si tu intensión es que estén anidadas lo normal es que las anides como tu ya lo tienes, pero tambien puedes utilizar el metodo `$.ajax.then()` Y tratarlo como si fuera una [promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas) (Dejare codigo de ejemplo mas abajo)

3- NO utilices el `async: false` en una request al servidor, lo que hace esta funcion es detener todo el codigo javascript que se este ejecutando en ese momento. Lo que podria afectar a otras funciones que estén trabajando en paralelo. La misma [documentacion](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#:%7E:text=As%20of%20jQuery%201.8%2C%20the,such%20as%20jqXHR.done()%20.) especifica que esta descontinuada y no se recomienda su uso

4-Esta no es una mejora tal vez pero si me pareció curioso que después de usar `swal` recargues la pagina después de dar click en el botón, técnicamente si un usuario da click muy rápido a la notificación, el resto de peticiones no se completarían o daría margen de error dependiendo de la velocidad en que se hagan las peticiones, a mi parecer no daría esa change al sistema de fallar.

```
function crearBalance() {
    let mail = document.getElementById('correo').value;
    let datings = document.getElementById('fecha').value;
    let idturn = document.getElementById('idTurnobal').value;
    let usexr = document.getElementById('usernamex').value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'CrearBalance.action',
        data:
            'tms=' +
            $('#tms').val() +
            '&ContenidoMetalicoCabeza=' +
            $('#contenidoMetalicoCabeza').val() +
            '&ContenidoMetalicoSR=' +
            $('#contenidoMetalicoSR'),
    }).then((resultCrearBalance) => {
        swal({
            title: 'Buen trabajo',
            text:
                'Se ingresaron los datos del balance para su revision!',
            type: 'success',
        });
        if (mail === 'A') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'reportpdf.action',
                data:
                    'asunto=' +
                    datings +
                    '&msg=' +
                    idturn +
                    '&usuarios=' +
                    usexr,
            }).then((resultReportPDF) => {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'Correos.action',
                    data:
                        'asunto=' +
                        datings +
                        '&msg=' +
                        idturn +
                        '&usuarios=' +
                        usexr,
                }).then((resultCorreos) => {
                    //Mas codigo
                })
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaria que cambiaras las llamadas **`$.ajax`** por el API actual del browser **`fetch()`**.

¿Por qué?, de esta manera podrías manejar mejor tus llamadas a tu server de una manera mas eficiente,

¿Cómo?

1. Evitarías el callback hell
2. Basarías tus 'anidaciones' en promesas
3. Mejorarías mucho la legibildiad de tu código
4. Harías la llamada nativa (sin el uso de ajax de jQuery)

Te dejo un ejemplo practico que encontre usando fetch API anidado:

```
var url = 'https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launches/latest';

var result = fetch(url, {
 method: 'get',
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.json(); // convertimos la respuesta que nos da el server en json
}).then(function(data) {
 //Despues de resolver el json hacemos la logica aqui es donde harias tu segunda llamada respecto a lo que te respondio la primera
var rocketId = data.rocket.rocket_id;
console.log(rocketId, '\n');
return fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/rockets/' + rocketId); 
// En este caso hacemos una segunda llamada usando las urls que nostrajo en la primera llamada
})
 .then(function(response) {
   return response.json(); //Volvemos a decodificar la respuesta a json
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Request failed', error) //cachamos cualquier error
  })

    //Llamamos a nuestro resultado
  result.then(function(r) {
    console.log(r); // Obtenemos el Resultado Final de la logica aplicada.
  });
```

Puede parecer confuso pero te aseguro que el uso de FETCH API es mucho mas fácil y mejor manejable que **`$.ajax`** de jQuery.

Comment: Claro,  es muy importante tener eso en cuenta tambien Gracias @BetaM